# org-mode: Export closest flagged subtree?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

After editing at a deeper sublevel I often have to do multiple `C-c C-u`'s (`outline-up-heading`) to get to the proper level before doing `C-c C-e C-s` to export the subtree. Is there a way to automate the process of searching upwards for the closest level flagged to be exported?

Comment: Use `org-up-heading-safe` in a loop, checking at each point for whatever condition you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify how the relevant subtree is flagged, but let's assume that it has an `export` tag. Then the following function will move point up to the closest heading that is explicitly tagged `export`. The function uses `org-up-heading-safe` in a loop, as mentioned in my comment: it will stop at the closest heading that is tagged `export` or if there is no such tag, it will stop at the top level heading that contains the current node:

```el
(defun my/org-up-to-export ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((found (member "export" (org-get-tags nil t)))
        top-level)
    (while (and (not found) (not top-level))
      (setq top-level (not (org-up-heading-safe)))
      (setq found (member "export" (org-get-tags nil t))))))
```

`org-up-heading-safe` returns the level of the heading that it moved to, or `nil` if it was not able to move - see its doc string with `C-h f org-up-heading`.

The function also uses `org-get-tags` at each level to get the tags list of the current heading - the second argument being `t` specifies that we are looking for an explicit "local" tag, disregarding inheritance; see the doc string of the function with `C-h f org-get-tags`.